# condition field password (Password Protection)

Tags: forms, password-protection

I created a webform (Registration) Via phpform.org but I want make a condition for a field (Password) Like that (if password field is equal to 'test' then show Submit field )

```
<li id="li_2" >
    <label class="description" for="element_2">Name </label>
    <span>
        <input id="element_2_1" name= "element_2_1" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="8" value=""/>
        <label>First</label>
    </span>
    <span>
        <input id="element_2_2" name= "element_2_2" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="14" value=""/>
        <label>Last</label>
    </span> 
    </li>       <li id="li_1" >
    <label class="description" for="element_1">Password </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_1" name="element_1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div> 
    </li>

                <li class="buttons">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="677911" />

            <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </li>
        </ul>
    </form> 
    <div id="footer">
        Generated by <a href="http://www.phpform.org">pForm</a>
    </div>
</div>
<img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">
</body>
```

Please how can I do that ?

Comment: be careful not to include password hints in this JScript, it is visible to the user...
so dont `if ($(this).val() == "the_password") {...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$(".buttons").hide();
$("#element_1").keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "test") {
        $(".buttons").show();
    } else {
        $(".buttons").hide();
    }
});
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/7UtHW/.

Comment: Thank's man =) ,but I have another question , I will put all that in one file and upload it on my website or there is another way .I'm just newbie =D

Comment: I heartily recommend you to parse some of the examples at [http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/), where you can try for yourself some examples (and see the source HTML at the same time). It doesn't make too much sense to put all those tutorials in my answer :)

Comment: Mr.Alex Please How can I make these two fields 'required' ?

Comment: Which ones? What do you mean by _required_? Please describe what should be the exact behavior.

Comment: for example , someone forgot to write his name in the form and he click submit ,the form warns that he must write his name (required)

Comment: Yeah that's what I want , Thank you again Mr.Alex =)